# less than or greater than query in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to generate a less than or greater than query in rails like the between range query. I have multiple query params and hence I do not want to use string literal for comparison.

```
if params["end_time"]
    if params["start_time"]
        params["end_time"] = params["end_time"].to_datetime
        query[:created_at] = ((params["start_time"])..params["end_time"])
    else
      query[:created_at] = #Need help with this
    end
end
```

Comment: Why build a `query` hash when you could `q = M.where(...); q = q.where(...)` to build the query directly piece by piece?

Comment: Hiya, have you had a read of the query-guide? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html it's pretty awesome. Specifically you'll want the `between` query... but definitely read the whole thing, it's worth it to level-up.

Answer (score 0):

```
def with_duration
    if(params['start_time'] && params['end_time'])
        {created_at: params['start_time']..params['end_time']}
    elsif(params['start_time'])
        return ["created_at > ?", "#{params['start_time']}"]
    elsif(params['end_time'])
        return ["created_at < ?", "#{params['end_time']}"]
    else
        return {}
    end
end
ModelName.where(with_duration)
```

Comment: I have a lot of query params created_at is just one of them. Would it be possible to club all the params with a generic hash query?

Comment: It is possible if you are sure that both start time and end time are available. Then you can add other params to this hash `{created_at: params['start_time']..params['end_time']}`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need to do nothing if params empty. So you can try this implementation.

```
def query_method(scope)
  return scope unless params["end_time"] && params["start_time"]

  scope.where.not(created_at: (params["start_time"]..params["end_time"]))
end
```